# How to setup a managed reference in a List with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, list, jackson

I have a list of `Car`s (actually an `ObservableList`, in a `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper`), and I have a schedule that has has an array of these `Car`s. What I want to do is have the cars in the list be `@JsonManagedReference` and the cars in the schedule be `@JsonBackReference`.

Here is the managed reference part:

```
private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<ObservableList<Car>> cars = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(new ObservableList(carExtractor()));

@JsonManagedReference("car")
@SuppressWarnings("unused") // Called by Jackson to deserialize cars
private void setCars(ObservableList<Car> cars){
    this.cars.set(cars);
}
```

And here is my back reference part (schedule):

```
@JsonBackReference("car")
private Car[] lanes;
```

But when I try to deserialize this, I get this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back reference 'car': no back reference property found from type [collection type; class com.neonorb.commons.ObservableList, contains [simple type, class com.neonorb.derbypro.core.Car]]
```

I was thinking, an easy way to fix this is to have a mixin and apply that to the list so that the cars themselves are getting the managed reference attribute rather than the list. But the problem with this is that I have multiple lists with different types (i.e. `Group`) so I can't apply this to the entire `ObservableList` class.

Before, in the schedule I was having an index number for the spot in the list the `Car` was we want, but this can get annoying with list reorders and stuff like that. I want a clean reference rather than an index number.

I do not want the array in the schedule to be a reference to the list, I want each car in the array to be a reference to each car in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not needing this managed/back reference stuff. All I did was annotate the bean that I only want one of with:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
```

Works like a charm!